# Custom Installer package using NSIS

Tags: installation, nsis

I have an installer where all the database, server, connection and authentication information is collected at the end of the installation.

Now I want to give an option to the user to  create a custom install package at the end of installation with all the database, server, connection and authentication information pre-configured.

So that when the custom install package is run for the next time,all the information previously entered is retained and the installation should complete without having the user to enter the configurations again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could store the information in a .ini file that the installer reads from if it is in the same directory as the installer (`$ExeDir`).

It is also possible to append data to the end of the installer .exe and [read it](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ReadCustomerData) back later but you would have to make a copy of the .exe because you cannot write to it while it is running.